# Angular router 3 routerLink not working

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 2.0.0-rc3 with router 3.0.0-alpha.8.

I have a `BookListComponent` with the following template:

```
<nav>
  <a routerLink="/new-book">New Book</a>
</nav>

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let book of books">{{ book.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

And then here's `BookListComponent` itself:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BookService } from '../book.service';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-book-list',
  templateUrl: 'book-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['book-list.component.css'],
  providers: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, BookService]
})
export class BookListComponent implements OnInit {
  books: any;

  constructor(private bookService: BookService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bookService.getList()
      .subscribe(response => this.books = response.json());
  }

}
```

Not only does the link not take me to the `/new-book` route (which, if visited "manually", works just fine), but the "link" isn't even a link - it's just black text.

How can I get the link to work?

Comment: `<a [routerLink]="['/new-book']">New Book</a>` might be worth a try. I have seen a bug report about routerLink with a string parameter. In any case update to router beta.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` under `providers` but it needed to be under `directives`. Moving it to `directives` fixed the problem.

Here's my new `BookListComponent`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BookService } from '../book.service';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-book-list',
  templateUrl: 'book-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['book-list.component.css'],
  providers: [BookService],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class BookListComponent implements OnInit {
  books: any;

  constructor(private bookService: BookService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bookService.getList()
      .subscribe(response => this.books = response.json());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are not missing the Router Outlet tag in the host's views HTML.

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

I use this as a reference:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: That didn't work, unfortunately. I already have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in `AppComponent`'s template. Adding another one to the same template where my link is didn't change anything.